# AES Decryption not working using with crypto js

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, aes

In my code I am encrypting data using AES encryption using crypto.js and i am decrypting the encrypted text
in java.

Encryption and Decryption are working correctly if i try to encrypt and decrypt both in javascript or java.But if i encrypt in javascript
and trying to decrypt in  java i am getting below error.

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly
>   padded    at
>   com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)

Below is my JSCode:

```
var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('584771624934175587013168');
var iv    = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('000000000000000000000000');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('1111', keyHex, {
    iv:iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log('encryptByAES key: ',encrypted.toString());
```

Below is my java  code.

```
String key = "584771624934175587013168";
String plainText = "1111";
public String encryptTextusingAES(String text, String kek) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] b= kek.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len= b.length;
    if (len> keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);
    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    return encoder.encode(results);
}

public String decryptTextusingAES(String text, String kek) throws Exception{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] b= kek.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len= b.length;
    if (len> keyBytes.length) len = keyBytes.length;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,keySpec,ivSpec);
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte [] results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
    return new String(results,"UTF-8");
}

How to decrypt correctly any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a block encryption such as AES, your input needs to be *padded* before encryption. There are various standard ways of doing this.

In your JS code your are specifying PKCS-7:

```
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
```

but in your Java code you are specifying PKCS-5:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Make sure you are using the same padding algorithm on both sides.

Comment: thanks, but PKCS5 padding is not exisits in javascript.

Comment: Feel free to vote up my post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172)